# Removing iframe from loading page. Using Laravel framework

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I've been stuck on getting this loading page/splash screen how it needs to be for the UI/UX to be acceptable.

The web app is built with laravel 4.2 for the backend.

For the loading page we have an embed google map using an iframe solution, as I had too many issues not using an iframe (multiple API conflicts). Once the main application is fully loaded it is supposed to transition into it but it doesn't, it just stays on the loading page as the iframe is stopping the transition into the front-end (Ember 1.8).

Does anyone know how to remove the iframe from the page upon main application has correctly loaded.

iframe code:

```
   <div id="map">

<iframe id="load-map"
width="1630px"
height="953px"
frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=AIzaSyCnQpBZ7Wtic3UQn3haLSTlYf9OtuusGGc&center=54.559322,-4.174804&zoom=6&maptype=roadmap"
</iframe>

</div>
<script>
function remove(){
 var frame = document.getElementById("load-map");
 frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
}

<?php
</script>

public function removeChild() {

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
remove();
</script>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Just remove the iframe when the app is loaded? Something like: `var map = document.getElementById("load-map");
map.parentNode.removeChild(map);`

Comment: @Steve I have updated post with script.. still doesn't work.

Comment: If you edit is accurate, you renamed the variable `map` to `frame` but forgot to change the last part: `frame.parentNode.removeChild(map);//<--map should be frame`

Comment: @Steve changed it to frame, still stuck on loading page..

Comment: How are you calling the remove function?

Comment: @Steve original post updated with the code block - thanks for your help so far, it's very frustrating.. been stuck on this all day